# Node.js SIGTERM implementation considerations

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an stateless node.js application. It is an api implemented with express which connects to a mongoDB database. Each request is completely independent from other requests (ergo stateless).

I would like to implement a SIGTERM in order to shutdown gracefully but I do not know what I should take into consideration.

What I know for sure is that I should close my db connection. But, if I just do that:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
  server.close(function () { //Stops express
    db.close(false, function() { //Closes database connection
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
});
```

Can I assure that no request is being interrupted by doing that? If not, how do I know if a request is being made and how do I wait for it to finish? Should I stop listening for requests during this time? If so, how?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `server` is a `http.Server` instance, calling `.close()` will stop the server from accepting new connections ([documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback)), but existing requests will continue to run until they're done.

The callback will get called only once all requests have been processed, so it's safe to assume that at that point you can close the database connection (there won't be any requests listening to it anymore).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, server is an http.Server, I just assumed that closig the db inside the callback would wait for server.close() to complete. Isn't it that how it works?

Comment: @PepRodejaFerrer you are correct, I checked: the callback is only called when all requests have been processed. I'll edit my answer accordingly.